# Using org.apache.commons.fileupload.ServletFileUpload in OSGi plugin on Domino 8.5.3

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, classloader, lotus-domino

I have a servlet which extends javax.servlet.HttpServlet.  I want to have it process files uploaded to it from a multipart form submission.

When I try to do the very minimum by POSTing data to this servlet. I get a classloader error (See below). I'm not duplicating jar files in my build path.

I'm a little stumped have you seen the same problem and fixed it?

The relevant bit of code is:

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

super.doPost(req, resp);

try{
if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)) {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Request is not multipart, please 'multipart/form-data' enctype for your form.");
}else{
System.out.println("OK");
}
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}finally{

}

}
```

And the error is something like this:

17/03/14 17:26: Exception Thrown
java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation: loader "sun/misc/Launcher$ExtClassLoader@23b423b4" previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest" defined by loader "org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader@6bb06bb"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:540)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:79)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1038)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:429)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Launcher.java:281)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(ServletFileUpload.java:68)
    at com.jasonhook.test.TestFileUpload.doPost(TestFileUpload.java:30)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:713)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.internal.ServletManager$ServletWrapper.service(ServletManager.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:59)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.adapter.osgi.OSGIModule.invokeServlet(OSGIModule.java:165)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.adapter.osgi.OSGIModule.access$0(OSGIModule.java:151)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.adapter.osgi.OSGIModule$1.invokeServlet(OSGIModule.java:132)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.adapter.osgi.AbstractOSGIModule.invokeServletWithNotesContext(AbstractOSGIModule.java:179)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.adapter.osgi.OSGIModule.doService(OSGIModule.java:126)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.adapter.osgi.OSGIService.doService(OSGIService.java:391)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)

Comment: It looks like this is an OSGi servlet.  How does your bundle manifest specify its dependency on the javax.servlet classes?  I suggest you add the contents of MANIFEST.MF to the original question.

Comment: More:  Based on the stack trace, I think your bundle is loading the wrong version of the javax.servlet classes, but that's just a hunch.  The bundle manifest might help diagnose the problem.